# Easy way to open Chrome Extensions using Omnibar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, address-bar

Is there an easy way to open an extension in Chrome using the Omnibar? For example, I have Tweetdeck in chrome...and if I type in Tweetdeck, nothing appears in the list in the omnibar (other than web pages etc)...But as soon as I click "See X recent pages in history..." it is the first option in the search results...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the Omnibar, but you can launch Chrome (or chromium) in app mode from the command line like this:

/usr/bin/chromium-browser --app-id="bjgihiafnlohlfegcngpknnjidiikblj"

(app-id culled from manage extensions page) (Windows users obviously should change path to reflect Windows)

This only works for web-apps like Tweetdeck or Oplop. The one regular extension I tried crashed Chrome.

If you pin a web-app to your desktop or app menu as a shortcut, you can launch Tweetdeck with a launcher like Gnome Do or Synapse, but that only applies to Linux users.

Answer (score 0):

Hrm, the only way to shorten that which I can think of would be to use the History Button extension:

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fofpnhmbgmmeaialapfddhbhfongoinh

This at least removes the keyboard -> mouse switch of pressing Ctrl+H then clicking in the history, now it's two short mouseclicks.

Never found any faster way however, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using Chrome 10.0.x.x and when I start typing in Tweetdeck, the first option is  **chrome-extension://... - TweetDeck** begins appearing...to problem solved!

It certainly didn't do this in Chrome 8...